# ASIHttpRequest POST JSON well, but AFNetworking is not

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I want to "POST" a JSON value to server and response a json databack.

The URL: http://solok.com:8080/soloo/phone/execute?content={"method":"tet_123","version","1"}, can get the right value(JSON) in browser.

ASIHTTPRequest way:

```
NSDictionary *postDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"tet_123",@"method",@"1",@"version",nil];
NSString *postString;

//Then convert the "postDic" to NSString, the value is:{"method":"tet_123","version","1"} assign to postString;
psotString = ...;
ASIFormDataRequest *req=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[req setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[req setPostValue:posStr forKey:@"content"];
[req startAsynchronous];
[req setDelegate:self];
[req setCompletionBlock:^{
   NSData *d = [req responseData];
   NSLog(@"respond is %@".d);
}
```

---

It works smoothly! But AFNetworkding is not, here is the code;

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"tet_123",@"method",@"1",@"version",nil];
NSDictionary *dic1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dic,@"content", nil];
[httpClient postPath:@"/soloo/phone/execute" parameters:dic1 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSDictionary *d = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
    NSLog(@"success is %@",d);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"fail");
}];
```

The output is: success is <>.

or i use another way of AFNetworking:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"path:@"/soloo/phone/execute" parameters:dic1];
AFJSONRequestOperation *ope = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"response %d",response.statusCode);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"fail%d JSON %@",response.statusCode,JSON);
}];
```

The respond code is 200, which means connection is correct, but still no the correct result.
Not sure why. Any help, thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is is the backend is a "GET" method, but i did "POST", meanwhile, i forgot: [Operation start] method.